# How to subscribe an SQS queue to an SNS topic with aws cdk?

Tags: typescript, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I first create a queue:

```
const notificationQueue: sqs.IQueue = new sqs.Queue(this, `${domain}-notificationsQueue`, {
  queueName: `${domain}-notificationsQueue.fifo`,
  fifo: true,
  contentBasedDeduplication: false
});
```

Now I need to subscribe this queue to an SNS topic (something like this but I need to pass in an IGrantable object - which I don't know how to do)

```
queue.grantConsumeMessages(grantee: iam.IGrantable)
```

So how do I create an IGrantable object that references a specific SNS topic?

Answer (score 6):

We can use `@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions`

we can import these:

```
import * as subscriptions from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions";
import * as sns from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns";
import * as sqs from "@aws-cdk/aws-sqs";
```

use `addSubscription` method on Sns.

```
const myTopic = new sns.Topic(this, "MyTopic");
const myQueue = new sqs.Queue(this, "MyQueue");
myTopic.addSubscription(new subscriptions.SqsSubscription(myQueue));
```

Comment: Doesn't this need an IAM policy to allow the topic to SendMessage to the queue?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell CDK will add necessary policies i.e. Resource Policy for SNS topic to allow SQS to consume. we don't have to write any additional code for it.

Comment: From my experience, CDK does not add permission to SNS to send messages to SQS, and for that reason, SNS 'may' (not sure why it still worked in one environment, and not another) fail to send message

Comment: Facing the same issue, CDK isn't automatically adding the policy to allow SNS to send messages to SQS